# Installing Missing executable for Buildozer

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I am new to coding in general and I have developed a simple app I want to convert to an .apk file.

I use Windows 10 so I have installed Oracle VM VirtualBox to run buildozer for conversion.

I have come across more different errors than I care to count, but the crux of my issues appear to be that I am missing executables:

```
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
```

I have attempted to use:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

but I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  automake autotools-dev m4
Suggested packages:
  autoconf-archive gnu-standards autoconf-doc libtool m4-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  autoconf automake autotools-dev m4
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 870 kB/1,067 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,943 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 autoconf all 2.69-10
Ign:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 autotools-dev all 20161112.1
Ign:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 automake all 1:1.15-5ubuntu1
Err:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main i386 autoconf all 2.69-10
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
Err:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main i386 autotools-dev all 20161112.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
Err:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main i386 automake all 1:1.15-5ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main a/autoconf/autoconf_2.69-10_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/autotools-dev/autotools-dev_20161112.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/automake-1.15/automake_1.15-5ubuntu1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have hit a wall after searching online for days looking for a solution but I have made no progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus) reached End of Life on January 13, 2018. On the VM, you have to upgrade from Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic. Please do the following:

1. `sudo sed -i 's/zesty/bionic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt upgrade`
4. `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
5. `sudo apt autoremove`
6. `sudo apt clean`
7. Reboot the system